# Taking data from 1 website(input) and pasting it to another website(input)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, web

I need to take a data of username, then check in db, which aunthefecator user has got and depends on aunthefecator send him the window where he can enter it and login in his account!

I have tryed to make it like a 1 form and the method was sent to another form but it doesn not work.

```
<form name="logon" action="check_login.php" method="POST" id="login">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <button type="submit">                                 
    <span>Log IN</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

I just redirecting on this page without getting data.

Comment: This will just submit to the other page and reload the window with the result from that other page.

Comment: If you want to send to that page without reloading, you need to use AJAX, and then parse the response.

Comment: Instead of sending to another web page, you should implement an API that can be used by all of them for single-signon.

Comment: Im bad with API , what is look like? it is like secure connection to the webserver?

Comment: It's a webserver script where the response is data instead of HTML, JSON is a common format.

Answer (score 0):

You must put this code in top of your php page, or if you want to check login in another page , you should put this code in destination page that you want to check login authentication. Remember to put your code about checking user and pass from database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[“username”] && $_POST[“password”]){
$user = $_POST[“username”];
$pass = $_POST[“password”];
//Check your db here and then replace your url that you want to reload client if user and pass was correct.
header(‘Location: http://yourURL.com’);
}else{
echo (“username or password was not correct”);
}
?>
```